# Generated variable is not the same as hard coded string. Both are the same values but returning a false when compared

Tags: powershell

I am pulling the CLI password for carbon black on an endpoint. I have a snippet that pulls the password from the server and places it into a variable.

I need to pass this variable containing the password to a command later however its not passing correctly (the command is irrelevant).

I hard coded a variable with actual value from the system and ran that into my command and it works perfectly fine.

So in a nutshell the pulled password from the server snippet does not equal the hard coded variable but they appear the same and are both strings.

Any tips on how to convert the pulled password into the correct format?

I checked gettype().fullname and theyre both the same format.

```
 $resource = "SEOMRESORUCE" + $Computer
 $url = "SOMEEML SOURCE"
 $configlist = "C:\Temp\configlistwithdeleteditems.xml"

 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback =      {$true}

 # download the CL file
 Write-Host "Finding CLI Password"
 $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 $wc.DownloadFile($url, $configlist)

 $webResponsey = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($resource)
 $webResponsey.Method = "GET"
 $webResponsey.ContentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'
 $webResponsey.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "SOMETOKEN")

 $Response= $webResponsey.GetResponse()
 $ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
 $ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
 $jsonresult = $ReadStream.ReadToEnd()

 $saveme = $jsonresult | Out-String
 $cliPassword = $saveme -replace '.*CLIPassword":"([^"]*)".*', '$1' 

 Write-Host "CLI password is " $cliPassword #this provides the same  value as $clipassword2

 $cliPassword2 = 'TAWR-SOWR-POYS-YAEZ'


 $cliPassword -eq $cliPassword2 #this equals False for whatever reason
```

Comment: try piping them to `Format-Hex` to see what is in the strings. that will let you see things like non-printing characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just modify your regex to get the desired results:

```
$cliPassword = $saveme -replace '(?s).*CLIPassword":"([^"]*)".*', '$1'
```

You need the singleline modifier (`(?s)`) because your json to string conversion is going to include linefeed and/or carriage returns. By default, the regex `.` character does not match newline characters. Without the singleline modifier, only the line with the CLIPassword text will be matched by the `-Replace` operator. The non-matched lines will still output.